# Assigning Image from URL with Dragonfly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, paperclip, dragonfly-gem

I'm using Dragonfly for handling images on a Rails 3.1 app. I'm struggling with assigning images to a model via the url.

I have this working fine in a form:

```
<%= form_for [@word, @game, @picture], :html => {:multipart => true} do |f| %> 
  <%= f.hidden_field :retained_image %>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :image, "upload pic" %><br />
    <%= f.file_field :image %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :image_url, "or pic URL" %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :image_url %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <% if @picture.image_uid? %>
    <label>Remove Picture?</label>
    <%= f.check_box :remove_image %>
    <% end %>
  </p>
  <p><%= f.submit %></p>
<% end %>
```

Dragonfly's documentation states:

Dragonfly provides an accessor for assigning directly from a url:

```
@album.cover_image_url = 'http://some.url/file.jpg'
```

But yet when I try in my console:

```
 => #<Picture id: nil, game_id: nil, user_id: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, image_uid: nil> 
ruby-1.9.2-p290 > picture.image_url = "http://i.imgur.com/QQiMz.jpg"
 => "http://i.imgur.com/QQiMz.jpg" 
ruby-1.9.2-p290 > picture
 => #<Picture id: nil, game_id: nil, user_id: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, image_uid: nil>
```

It seems to be returning the string of the URL I'm trying to give to Dragonfly, not opening and pulling the image like in the form.

Is there something I'm missing when trying to assign an image based off a url? It seems like it should be pretty straight forward but I can't seem to get anything to work in the ruby console.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

are you sure it's not working? What happens when you type (after assigning from a url)

```
picture.image
```

or

```
picture.image.size
```

for example?

It won't set an image_uid until it's saved, but you have picture.image available to play with.

The actual fetching from the url happens lazily, i.e. only when needed. Calling 'size' above triggers it, for example.

Comment: First off, thanks Mark for the amazing gem. Second, wow do I feel silly. I was doing some fetching and something like: picture.save if picture.image_uid #obviously this will not work and I didn't test thoroughly enough. Thanks a ton, works great.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem where, through a form, the :image_url was not creating an :image_uid on save.  Everything worked fine in the rails console.

It worked with the :image_url once I added it as a param in my controller.  I thought :image would handle :image_url on save, but instead I had to explicitly pass :image_url as a param for saving.

Comment: May be you should add some code to illustrate your solution.

Comment: Surely he's a time traveller and means adding :image_url to `params.require(:my_model).permit(:foo, :bar, :image_url)` in rails 4.